# jetty - LinkageError: loader constraint violation for org/eclipse/jetty/util/security/Credential

Tags: jetty, classloader, jetty-9

I have implemented my own login module using jetty JASS login service. Creating my own login module ,deploying my WAR file on jetty server . I have extended jetty **AbstractLoginModule** to implement or use jetty jass login service. Once you extend this all you need to do is implement **getUserInfo** method of it.

I am doing it similar way like this,

```
  @Override
    public UserInfo getUserInfo(String username) throws Exception {
        Credential credential = Credential.getCredential(username);
        List<String> roles = new ArrayList<String>();
        roles.add("**");        
        return new UserInfo(username, credential, roles);

    }
```

when jetty is not deployed or using any https module it works fine but when i use https module it throws linkage error and does not allow me to connect on https or https. My authentication fails.

**Error**:

```
    2015-12-23 12:34:00.053:WARN:oejj.JAASLoginService:qtp109961541-14:
javax.security.auth.login.LoginException: java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: when resolving method "org.eclipse.jetty.jaas.spi.UserInfo.<init>(Ljav
a/lang/String;Lorg/eclipse/jetty/util/security/Credential;Ljava/util/List;)V" the class loader (instance of org/eclipse/jetty/webapp/WebAppClassLoader) of the curren
t class, sigma/git/ctr/loginmodule/SigmaAALoginModule, and the class loader (instance of sun/misc/Launcher$AppClassLoader) for the method's defining class, org/eclip
se/jetty/jaas/spi/UserInfo, have different Class objects for the type org/eclipse/jetty/util/security/Credential used in the signature<|?at sigma.git.ctr.loginmodule
.SigmaAALoginModule.getUserInfo(SigmaAALoginModule.java:192)<|?at sigma.git.ctr.loginmodule.SigmaAALoginModule.login(SigmaAALoginModule.java:146)<|?at sun.reflect.Na
tiveMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)<|?at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)<|?at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(U
nknown Source)<|?at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)<|?at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invoke(Unknown Source)<|?at javax.security.auth.login
.LoginContext.access$000(Unknown Source)<|?at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext$4.run(Unknown Source)<|?at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext$4.run(Unknown
Source)<|?at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)<|?at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invokePriv(Unknown Source)<|?at javax.security.au
th.login.LoginContext.login(Unknown Source)<|?at org.eclipse.jetty.jaas.JAASLoginService.login(JAASLoginService.java:233)<|?at org.eclipse.jetty.security.authenticat
ion.LoginAuthenticator.login(LoginAuthenticator.java:61)<|?at org.eclipse.jetty.security.authentication.BasicAuthenticator.validateRequest(BasicAuthenticator.java:92
```

I have also tried excluding all UserInfo dependency jars while packaging. I cannot exclude  jetty-util jar which contains **Credentials Classes**. If i do it throws NoClassDefFoundError.

Please suggest.

Comment: Now if i remove the jetty-util jar and set " Credential credential =null;" Then i just byapss the credential  and everthing works fine. But this is just workaround not exact solution. In my case userInfo object makes no sense so i just ignore seeting it to dummy object .
ref https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=394490